# Emacs is ignoring my path when it runs a compile command

Tags: ruby, macos, emacs, rvm

I'm trying to get a compile command (rake cucumber) to run with a specific ruby version on my Mac OS X system, I use rvm to do this currently in the terminal. My ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist has the correct path in it, but emacs insists on prepending to this path and therefore making it useless.  I've also tried:

```
(when (equal system-type 'darwin)
  (setenv "PATH" (concat "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249%global/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/bin"))
  (push "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/bin" exec-path)
  (push "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin" exec-path)
  (push "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin" exec-path)
  (push "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249%global/bin" exec-path)
  (push "/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/bin" exec-path))
```

It was the desperate attempt of an emacs beginner to get what I wanted.  It *still* prepends in front of it, so my path ends up being:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin:/Users/fearoffish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p249%global/bin
```

I don't want /usr/bin and others prepending, I want *my* path first and the emacs prepended path to be at the end, I reckon this would fix my problem.

I test this by simply opening Aquamacs and running `meta-x compile` and then `echo $PATH`.

Any ideas?

Comment: All of the answers are about shell commands, but they differ from compile commands, don't they?

Comment: I'm experiencing this, even though I've commented out path_helper in /etc/profile, and my $SHELL is zsh.

Comment: For anyone still hitting this issue: have a look at https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A small modification to the solution by sanityinc (couldn't find a way to enter it in the comments above -- is that just me?)

- I use `-l` option to the shell to force a login shell (which reads `.profile` or `.bash_profile`), rather than an interactive shell (which only reads `.bashrc`).
- I do some string trimming on the returned path (as inspection shows a newline sneaking in).

Modified code:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell 
      (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]\n]*$" "" 
        (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -l -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
(when (equal system-type 'darwin) (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

Comment: Nice! I tried sanityinc's and was perplexed but your changes fixed it for me!

Comment: @spacemanaki: Actually, I've since switched from Carbon Emacs to Aquamacs (http://aquamacs.org/) which, among many other niceties, gets this right out of the box. It's doesn't feel quite emacsy at first, but it has certainly grown on me.

Comment: I actually started with Aquamacs when I first got this Macbook in August, but I switched to Carbon Emacs for some reason but I can't remember why. Going back and trying this in Aquamacs was actually what lead to me to check what Emacs thought the PATH was. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, the problem with the code in my answer was the trailing whitespace in the shell command output. `string-rtrim` tidies it up more concisely than `replace-regexp-in-string`. For future reference, my up-to-date code for this lives here: https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/init-exec-path.el

Comment: I'm confused; how does this function affect the compile shell? I'm in a situation where my exec-path is already _right_, but the PATH in the *compilation* buffer is wrong.

Comment: `echo` from `gnu coreutils` has `-n` option for trailing newline not to show up.

Comment: An improved and modified version of the code snippet is now published as elisp library called [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell); installable packages are available in Marmalade and [Melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/).

Answer (score 11):

Everyone seems to have misunderstood the original issue: the path is already setup correctly in Emacs, and the correct path is already passed to the shell started by the compile command! So what gives? Here is the answer:

In MacOS X, there is a small tool called `path_helper(1)`.  It is called by default from `/etc/profile`, which is executed by Bash on shell startup.  When you start a compilation from Emacs, it launches a shell (which by default is Bash on MacOS X), and therefore executes this `path_helper` tool. And here comes the key point: `path_helper` *rearranges your path*, moving the standard directories like `/usr/bin` in front of your custom added directories, no matter where you originally added them.  Try this yourself by opening a shell and first having a look at what PATH is, and then execute `/usr/lib/path_helper` and have look at the resulting PATH!

The brute force solution for you might be to simply comment out the call to `path_helper` in `/etc/profile`. Note however that then you won't automatically get the paths in `/etc/paths.d` setup by `path_helper`, which is the tool's main purpose.

Comment: This problem still exists and this answer is correct.  I had to edit /etc/zshenv but same idea.  To see the distinction, check this out:

    `(defun my-compile-test ()

      "tests path in compile"

      (interactive)

      (compile "echo $SHELL; echo $PATH; exit 1")

      )`

If you define that function and run it, you can get a picture of what is happening _inside_ the *compilation* buffer.  Recommend!

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  Bizarre markdown engine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Mac, so I cannot test this directly, but this can all be found in the *info* page [Interactive Inferior Shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html).

When you start a shell in Emacs, the process that gets spawned is the program in the Emacs variable `explicit-shell-file-name` (and if that is `nil`, the environment variables `ESHELL` and `SHELL` are used).

It then sends the contents of `~/.emacs_*shellname*` (e.g. if your shell is `csh`, then `~/.emacs_csh` would be sent over.  Also, the appropriate .rc files for `csh` program is sourced, so you can update that as well (in my case `.cshrc`).  Additionally, you can wrap customizations in the .rc file with a check for the environment variable `INSIDE_EMACS` (which which Emacs sets before it runs a shell).

You need to update those files to change the path in the shell, not the Emacs variable `exec-path`.  `exec-path` - which is just a list of directories *Emacs* uses to find executable programs.  The behavior of the executables are not affected by changes to `exec-path`.

Answer (score 2):

I find the environment.plist scheme on Macs pretty ugly, so I use the following snippet, which assumes you want Emacs to use the same PATH that you see in your Terminal.app:

> ```
> (defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
>   (let ((path-from-shell (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -i -c 'echo $PATH'")))
>     (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
>     (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
> ```

(This works for me in Emacs 23; haven't tried it in other versions, but I'd expect it to work.)

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe. replace path string with yours.

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/opt/swank-clojure/src/emacs")

Answer (score 0):

As far as I observed, Emacs takes the path variable from the shell it is launched from, so one solution is to change $PATH in the shell before you launch Emacs.

One other approach I used, which is more flexible, is to use a Makefile and append a "source ~/script_that_set_path" in front of each make commands you have.

Comment: On a Mac, that's not the case; GUI programs launched from Finder don't inherit the environment of the desktop or the user's shell.

Comment: Ah sorry but I never used a Mac; my observation only pertains to windows and linux. Does starting Emacs from terminal (or equivalents in Mac) work? I would (again) suggest trying the Makefile method since that's the only way I found that reliably works (I also struggled a lots with getting PATH right for compilation).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many different approaches to this that ended up not using emacs to setup my compilation command environment.

What I do now is to create a run_helper.sh file that simply initializes a clean environment and then uses `exec $*` to execute the command passed as argument to `run_helper.sh`

This `run_helper.sh` is usually project specific, but I keep a template which I use to start with when I create a new project.

Then I simple run `compile` from emacs like `bash run_helper.sh rspec path/to/tests` for example.

If I am using this to run ruby tests, my helper initializes RVM to use the proper ruby and gemset. If I am using some other language it may just export required environment variables or perform some other initialization, but this way I can do it in bash script instead of always having to mess with emacs paths and elisp every time I start a new project.

Here's an example of a `run_helper.sh` file

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/simao/Documents/sp

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads the proper ruby and gemset from .rvmrc

export RAILS_ENV=test

exec $*
```

This also makes my tests run faster because I have lots of stuff in my `.zshrc` that I don't want to load just to run some tests.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with two things.

First I followed sanityinc advice

> An improved and modified version of the code snippet is now published as elisp library called exec-path-from-shell; installable packages are available in Marmalade and Melpa

I still had a problem with compile commands. Valko Sipuli is right there was a problem involving path_helper.

I commented the corresponding line in /etc/profile and it did not help. Problem still there.
I don't use bash but zsh. Digging a little I found /etc/zshenv. This file also calls path_helper.

After commenting the path_helper section in /etc/zshenv my path is finally correct