# pdflatex command not working in Emacs terminal mode

Tags: macos, emacs, latex, environment-variables, pdflatex

I have some problem with the Emacs terminal mode. 
I'm a mac user and I use Emacs downloaded from emacsformacosx.com; I installed also ESS and AucTex.

I work with R, LaTex, Sweve and, I menage all with Emacs. When I want to compile the Sweave file I open the terminal and I use the "*R CMD Sweave myfile.Rnw*" command to generate a myfile.tex file. After this I use "*pdflatex myfile.tex*" command, to compile the LaTex file.

All these command work well if used in the terminal application of osx but, the pdflatex command doesn't work if I use the Emacs teminal mode:

*bash: pdflatex: command not found*

Do you have any suggestion?

**EDIT**
Thanks for your suggestion, I resolved my problem adding to my .emacs this:

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell 
      (replace-regexp-in-string "[[:space:]\n]*$" "" 
        (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -l -c 'echo $PATH'"))))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
(when (equal system-type 'darwin) (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

I found it at [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266905/emacs-is-ignoring-my-path-when-it-runs-a-compile-command)

Best
Riccardo

---

Comment: This seems like more of a superuser.com question.  The odds are it's a problem with your $PATH environment variable, which is getting set properly in Terminal but not in Emacs shell windows.  I don't know enough about OSX quirks to help you figure that out.

Comment: Can you move the edit down to an answer please?  That way it fits better with the Q&A format of Stack Overflow, and you can receive upvotes and accept your own answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, environment variables for GUI programs are set in `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.  There are many Emacs specific work arounds like using `(setenv "PATH" (shell-command-to-string "echo -n $PATH"))` which you can find scattered across Stack Overflow and the internet in general.