# Problems with pdflatex in emacs org-export-as-pdf

Tags: macos, shell, pdf, emacs, org-mode

I have some problems with the emacs org-mode. When I use the command org-export-as-pdf in org-mode, I got the error:

```
/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found [3 times]
```

I am a Mac OS X(10.7) user and the version of emacs is 24.2. I downloaded the Tex Live from the official website and it was installed at `/usr/local/texlive`. I knew the env variables of emacs shell is different from user's terminal, so I tried this command:

```
M-! $PATH
```

it printed:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory
```

then I typed some commands below:

```
$which pdflatex
/usr/texbin

$ln -s /usr/texbin/pdflatex /usr/bin
```

and then I turned back to emacs, and tried org-export-as-pdf again, the same problem still existed.
I am confused and I need your help ;-)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2566945/605276 I'm calling that function in my `.emacs` for setting path.

Comment: @Juancho it worked pretty well, thanks ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs is ignoring my path when it runs a compile command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266905/emacs-is-ignoring-my-path-when-it-runs-a-compile-command)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `pdflatex` directory to the Emacs `PATH` environment variable, instead of the symbolic link, e.g. add this to `~/.emacs`:

```el
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/texbin"))
```

and source it again with `M-x load-file` and type `~/.emacs`. And now `C-c C-e lp` in Org-mode works:

```
PDF file produced.
```

(Cross-posted on [Unix.StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366294/org-mode-doesnt-export-to-pdf/448011#448011).)